# Python TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index

Tags: python, tensorflow

The following code uses audio files to create a matrix of features in `tensorflow`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

directory = "audio_dataset/*.wav"

filenames = tf.train.match_filenames_once(directory)

init = (tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())

count_num_files = tf.size(filenames)
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
filename, file_contents = reader.read(filename_queue)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    num_files = sess.run(count_num_files)

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for i in range(num_files):
        audio_file = sess.run(filename)
        print(audio_file)
```

this is a toolkit that converts audio from time to frequency domain:

```
from bregman.suite import *


chromo = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
max_freqs = tf.argmax(chromo, 0)


def get_next_chromogram(sess):
    audio_file = sess.run(filename)
    F = Chromagram(audio_file, nfft=16384, wfft=8192, nhop=2205)
    return F.X


def extract_feature_vector(sess, chromo_data):
    num_features, num_samples = np.shape(chromo_data)
    freq_vals = sess.run(max_freqs, feed_dict={chromo: chromo_data})
    hist, bins = np.histogram(freq_vals, bins=range(num_features + 1))
    return hist.astype(float) / num_samples


def get_dataset(sess):
    num_files = sess.run(count_num_files)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    xs = []
    for _ in range(num_files):
        chromo_data = get_next_chromogram(sess)
        x = [extract_feature_vector(sess, chromo_data)]
        x = np.matrix(x)
        if len(xs) == 0:
            xs = x
        else:
            xs = np.vstack((xs, x))
    return xs
```

this clusters the data around two centroids:

```
k = 2
max_iterations = 100

def initial_cluster_centroids(X, k):
    return X[0:k, :]

def assign_cluster(X, centroids):
    expanded_vectors = tf.expand_dims(X, 0)
    expanded_centroids = tf.expand_dims(centroids, 1)
    distances = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(expanded_vectors, expanded_centroids)), 2)
    mins = tf.argmin(distances, 0)
    return mins

def recompute_centroids(X, Y):
    sums = tf.unsorted_segment_sum(X, Y, k)
    counts = tf.unsorted_segment_sum(tf.ones_like(X), Y, k)
    return sums / counts

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    X = get_dataset(sess)
    centroids = initial_cluster_centroids(X, k)
    i, converged = 0, False
    while not converged and i < max_iterations:
        i += 1
        Y = assign_cluster(X, centroids)
        centroids = sess.run(recompute_centroids(X, Y))
    print(centroids)
```

but Im getting the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "components.py", line 776, in <module>
    X = get_dataset(sess)
  File "ccomponents.py", line 745, in get_dataset
    chromo_data = get_next_chromogram(sess)
  File "coffee_components.py", line 728, in get_next_chromogram
    F = Chromagram(audio_file, nfft=16384, wfft=8192, nhop=2205)
  File "/Volumes/Dados/Documents/Education/Programming/Machine Learning/Manning/book/BregmanToolkit-master/bregman/features.py", line 143, in __init__
    Features.__init__(self, arg, feature_params)
  File "/Volumes/Dados/Documents/Education/Programming/Machine Learning/Manning/book/BregmanToolkit-master/bregman/features_base.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.extract()
  File "/Volumes/Dados/Documents/Education/Programming/Machine Learning/Manning/book/BregmanToolkit-master/bregman/features_base.py", line 213, in extract
    self.extract_funs.get(f, self._extract_error)()
  File "/Volumes/Dados/Documents/Education/Programming/Machine Learning/Manning/book/BregmanToolkit-master/bregman/features_base.py", line 711, in _chroma
    if not self._cqft():
  File "/Volumes/Dados/Documents/Education/Programming/Machine Learning/Manning/book/BregmanToolkit-master/bregman/features_base.py", line 588, in _cqft
    self._make_log_freq_map()
  File "/Volumes/Dados/Documents/Education/Programming/Machine Learning/Manning/book/BregmanToolkit-master/bregman/features_base.py", line 353, in _make_log_freq_map
    mxnorm = P.empty(self._cqtN) # Normalization coefficients        
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

as far as I'm concerned, `range`is an `int`and not a `float`.

could someone please point me the error here?

Comment: Where is `range`? It's not there in the stack trace. That seems to be complaining about the `X = get_dataset(sess)` line.

Comment: yes, and `get_dataset(sess)` on its turn, is a function (see above) with an iteration using (`range()`). usually this error refers to the fact the you use a `float` inside `range`, but i'm not sure here.

Comment: Perhaps you can check what value `audio_file` has in `get_next_chromogram()`? That's the only non-integer being passed on to `Chromagram()`.

Comment: @Antimony `audio_file` prints a path `('AUDIO VALUE', 'audio_dataset/Wicked.wav')`to a wav. file

Comment: What is `AUDIO_VALUE`? Perhaps it should only be referencing the path? I'm not quite sure what datatype `Chromagram()` accepts.

Comment: AUDIO VALUE is just a pointer for when I print code run, to help me locate the variable. I'm not sure either. It is a class from Bregman tookit, I reckon. but it makes sense to be a path to an audio file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using Python 3, but the Bregman Toolkit was written in Python 2. The error comes from [this line](https://github.com/bregmanstudio/BregmanToolkit/blob/069447b9ced6747eef97b2c23a13b10806f0d15c/bregman/features_base.py#L353):

```
mxnorm = P.empty(self._cqtN)
```

`self._cqtN` is a `float`. In Python 2, the pylab library accepts floats as input:

```
pylab.empty(5.0)
__main__:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

However, in Python 3 you get the same error as you do:

```
pylab.empty(5.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

You should be able to fix this error by just editing the line in the file I linked above and cast it to an int:

```
mxnorm = P.empty(int(self._cqtN))
```

However, I'd be surprised if there weren't any other errors due to the incompatible versions. You might want to try using Python 2 or look for an alternative to the Bregman Toolkit.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm using a `Python 2.X` conda enviroment for that. that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `castself._cqtN` to `int` in line 353 and 357 in feature_base.py

There are 
    `mxnorm = P.empty(int(self._cqtN))`

and
    `for i in P.arange(int(self._cqtN))])`